# Jquery, how to get previous selected dropdown value for multiple dropdowns using the same class?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently using `Jquery Repeater`, so I may have multiple dropdowns depending on how many the users added dropdowns.

My goal is to get previous selected dropdown value for each of individual dropdowns after it is changed.

But the problem is, I'm using the same class so it read the value that whichever I changed.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        var show_previous_1;
    $('.rank').on('focus', function () {
            show_previous_1 = this.value;
    })

    $(document).on('change keyup', '.rank', function() {
            $('#show_previous_1').text(show_previous_1);
        show_previous_1 = this.value;
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="rank">
    <option value="0">-Select Your Rank-</option>
    <option value="1">Airman</option>
    <option value="2">Senior Airman</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
<span id="show_previous_1"></span>
<br>
<br>
<select class="rank">
    <option value="0">-Select Your Rank-</option>
    <option value="1">Airman</option>
    <option value="2">Senior Airman</option>
</select>
<span id="show_previous_2"></span>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rht15dzy/

Comment: Please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem in your post and **don't just include a link to Fiddle**. Links rot, and your post should stand alone from any other resource; this question will lose any value to future visitors if jsFiddle is blocked or goes away in the future!

Comment: edited...sorry didnt know it has rules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Id-free solution based on two elements: `.rank` - for our dropdowns and `.show-rank` for output previous values. You can have as many dropdowns with output as you wish.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    // array of previously selected items for all items with class 'rank'
    var previously_selected=[];

    $(document).on('change', '.rank', function() {
      // find next closest output with class 'rank-show' for current dropdown
      var output=$(this).nextAll('.rank-show')[0];    
      // current doprdown index by class 'rank'
      var dropdownIndex=$(this).parent().children('.rank').index(this); 
      if (typeof previously_selected[dropdownIndex] !== 'undefined') {
        //output previous value
        $(output).text(previously_selected[dropdownIndex]);         
      } else {
        //output 0 as default previous value
        $(output).text(0); 
      }
      // set current value as previous for next dropdown change
      previously_selected[dropdownIndex]=$(this).val();       
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="rank">
    <option value="0">-Select Your Rank-</option>
    <option value="1">Airman</option>
    <option value="2">Senior Airman</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
<span class="rank-show"></span>
<br>
<br>
<select class="rank">
    <option value="0">-Select Your Rank-</option>
    <option value="1">Airman</option>
    <option value="2">Senior Airman</option>
</select>
<span class="rank-show"></span>
<br/>
<br/>
<select class="rank">
    <option value="0">-Select Your Rank-</option>
    <option value="1">Airman</option>
    <option value="2">Senior Airman</option>
</select>
<span class="rank-show"></span>
<br/>
<br/>
<select class="rank">
    <option value="0">-Select Your Rank-</option>
    <option value="1">Airman</option>
    <option value="2">Senior Airman</option>
    <option value="3">Senior Birdman</option>
</select>
<span  class="rank-show"></span>
```

Comment: this is what I'm looking for...but the problem is, i dont have any idea to make an increment id for `jquery repeater`...but `jquery repeater` increment it names each time user added a dropdown...`e.g : name="rank_items[0][rank]", name="rank_items[1][rank]", name="rank_items[2][rank]"`

Comment: @LearnProgramming I think it should be in your new question with more information about your problem. If my answer is right, please mark it.

Answer (score 1):

Now you can get Value of any Selected one by using span id

```js
$('.rank').on('focus ', function() {
  $(this).next().text($(this).val())
})

$(document).on('change keyup', '.rank', function() {
  $(this).next().next().text($(this).val())

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="rank">
  <option value="0">-Select Your Rank-</option>
  <option value="1">Airman</option>
  <option value="2">Senior Airman</option>
</select>
Last :<span id="show_previous_a1"></span> Now :<span id="show_previous_a2"></span>
<br>
<br>
<select class="rank">
  <option value="0">-Select Your Rank-</option>
  <option value="1">Airman</option>
  <option value="2">Senior Airman</option>
</select>
Last :<span id="show_previous_b1"></span> Now : <span id="show_previous_b2"></span>
```

Comment: The code shows only the current selected dropdown value...my goal is to get the previous selected dropdown value

Comment: Please tryout this

Answer (score 0):

First get the array of all the `select` dropdowns. Attach `change` listener to the dropdown and when changed
find the index of changed `select` and then you can get the value of previously selected dropdown using `index-1`

```js
const selects = $('select');

$('select').on('change', function() {
    const index = selects.index($(this));
    if(index !== 0) {
        console.log("Previous dropdown value", selects[index-1].value);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="rank">
    <option value="0">-Select Your Rank-</option>
    <option value="1">Airman</option>
    <option value="2">Senior Airman</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
<span id="show_previous_1"></span>
<br>
<br>
<select class="rank">
    <option value="0">-Select Your Rank-</option>
    <option value="1">Airman</option>
    <option value="2">Senior Airman</option>
</select>
<span id="show_previous_2"></span>
```

Comment: the dropdowns should not be connected to each other...my goal is to get the previous dropdown value on each individual dropdown

Comment: @LearnProgramming - The dropdowns are not connected. This is what the solution does, it get the previous select value for individual dropdown.